# Automatic creation of Test Plan in Azure TFS using python

Tags: python, tfs, azure-devops, test-plan

I have a problem with automatic creation of Test Plans in Azure TFS, by POST method in python.
When I'm creating it manually, in UI, everything works, and when I try to find this work item eg. `http://xxx/tfs/test/Project/_apis/test/plans/266801?api-version=5.0` - everything is OK and I get JSON.

My code:

```
def TestPlan(title=None, description=None):
    def wrapper(func):
        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':' + token, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorization
            }
            URL = url + '/' + project + '/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test Plan?' + api_version
            body = [
                {
                    "op": "add",
                    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
                    "value": title
                },
                {
                    "path": "/fields/System.Description",
                    "op": "add",
                    "value": description
                },
                {
                    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId",
                    "op": "add",
                    "value": automationId(func)
                }
            ]
            requests.post(URL, json=body, headers=headers)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner_wrapper
    return wrapper
```

When I'm using my code, work item is created, but only in UI. When I try to find it in API, a have an error:
`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Test plan 266800 not found.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.TestObjectNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi","typeKey":"TestObjectNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`
When I click in this work item in UI, I have this:
[image: azure test plan error]
I think I need to add a rootSuite durring creation of Test Plan, but how to do that?
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use the work item API to create a test plan (`_apis/wit/workitems`)?

You have to use the test plan API (`_apis/testplan/plans`). Here are examples: [Test Plans - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20%20plans/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples)

Comment: That was it. I didn't notice that I was using the wrong url. Thank you.